# Update immutable state with dynamic key in redux

Tags: redux, immutable.js

i have this initialState

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  list: [],
  entities: {},
  something: {
    otherOne: false,
    otherTwo: false,
  },
});
```

and i want update the object `something` with a function like this:

```
[UPDATE_SOMETHING]: (state, { key }) => { // <== key is the name of the nested props
    return state.merge({
      filterBy: {[key]: !state.get('key')},
    });
  ),
```

but it does not work...how i can update the state dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[UPDATE_SOMETHING]: (state, {key}) => {
  const something = state.get('something').withMutations(s => {
    s.set(key, !s.get(key));
  });
  return state.set('something', something);
),
```

Something like that could help?

Comment: What is this => " [SYNTAX] :" --- I'd like to do this but don't recognize what this first part represents.

Comment: @zero_cool check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names